# Load from absolute path AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to include the abosolute path of each load because I have rewritten the url and want to esnure that `populateResults.php` loads

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#results").load("functions/populateResults.php");  //initial page number to load
  $(".pagination").bootpag({
     total: <?php echo $pages; ?>,
     page: 1,
     maxVisible: 5
  }).on("page", function(e, num){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/content/ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>');
    $("#results").load("functions/populateResults.php", {'page':num});
  });

});

</script>
```

I am not sure and don't think doing /functions/populateResult would work.

Update

```
<?php $root_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>

<script>

var root_url = '<?= $root_url ?>';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#results").load(root_url + "/functions/populateResults.php");  //initial page number to load
  $(".pagination").bootpag({
     total: <?php echo $pages; ?>,
     page: 1,
     maxVisible: 5
  }).on("page", function(e, num){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="/content/ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>');
    $("#results").load(root_url + "/functions/populateResults.php", {'page':num});
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: These aren't absolute paths, they're relative. Are you getting any javascript errors? Does `populateResults.php` live in `/functions/populateResults.php` or is it `/courses/functions/populate...`

Comment: I think @user3907211 knows he/she has relative paths, but instead wants to work with absolute paths

Comment: without url rewritting it works fine, but the problem is that for instance searchPage.php?crs_category=business gets rewritten to category/business and where the populateResult is root of website/functions/populateResults.php

Comment: @user3907211 , your last comment just confused me. Can you provide more details? is this script its own script file or is it embedded in your html/php?

Comment: yeah i was hoping not to. your right about what i want. absolute path for these  url to that it start from the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do: Use PHP to get your root url, set that to a variable and send it to JS to use it where you wish.

```
<?php
$base_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
<script>
    var base_url = '<?= $base_url ?>';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#results").load(base_url + "/functions/populateResults.php");
        //.. your other code..
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have include an update under my initial post. for some reason its not loading. on console it doesnt show anything\

Comment: hmm.. do you have teamviewer? I have some time right now if you want I can help you remotely.